# Python and Phishing links: detect browser blockpages

Tags: python, web-scraping, url, browser, phishing

I am trying to create a small python script to check the following:

- if when a URL is opened in a browser a blocking page is shown to the user with a phishing warning

An example of a blockpage from Firefox is shown below

[image]

I tried playing with the ***request*** package but with little success.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions for me on how to approach this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

These warnings are powered by the Google Safe Browsing project which has an API you can integrate with (i.e. without needing to use a browser).

For high volumes of lookups you should use the [Update API](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/update-api) which downloads a local database which is queried first before confirming a result using the online API.

For small volumes of lookups you can use the [Lookup API](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/lookup-api) which makes a call to the online API for every lookup.

For Python, the [pysafebrowsing](https://pypi.org/project/pysafebrowsing/) implements the Lookup API and can be used like this:

```
from pysafebrowsing import SafeBrowsing
s = SafeBrowsing(KEY)
r = s.lookup_urls(['http://malware.testing.google.test/testing/malware/'])
print(r)
> {'http://malware.testing.google.test/testing/malware/': {'platforms': ['ANY_PLATFORM'], 'threats': ['MALWARE', 'SOCIAL_ENGINEERING'], 'malicious': True, 'cache': '300s'}}
```